# Network traffic monitoring windows through SNMP

Tags: windows, networking, interface, snmp, monitor

I want to make a script which will help me to monitor the network interface traffic on  Windows 7 through SNMP. Which language would be more suitable and how can i start with it?

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go with either Perl or Tcl.  These two scripting languages are  used widely for network related scripting. To start, all you have to do is browse the internet thoroughly. You can find a good number of tutorials online.

Comment: Thank you for revert.I was also planning to write in php but i am using XAMPP and i am not able to find any web server where i can use SNMP. can you help me with that.

Comment: Firstly, what is the cost that you're ready to incur for setting up a server? You need to find answers for a handful of questions.. What is the functionality of the server?  Does it support low scale, medium scale or large scale?

Comment: I work in company which is an ISP. so we have pretty much a lot of servers and large scale. Basically my task is i need to connect to some switch through SNMP find the upload and download rate (timeinterval refresh every 5 sec)

Comment: See if [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-1828/gbroo/index.html) helps.. You may also look into [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-5666-10/essnmp.htm) and [this one](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.dgwa400%2Fimwziu18470.htm) as well..